# How to create android library that depends on realm

Tags: android, realm

Right now I have a library that has a dependency on realm 0.87 (and several apps that are using this library).
As of now, I am looking for the way to upgrade to realm 1.x, but I have not found any documentation on how to apply realm plugin to the library project.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: asked question on behalf at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/511#issuecomment-241715546

Comment: ....by the way, have you seen the relevant [library example on Realm-Java's Github](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/moduleExample/library/build.gradle)?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, thanks for pointing. I will check it out

Comment: @EpicPandaForce , it just works. Please post it as an answer so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Realm's [library example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/moduleExample/library/build.gradle), it seems to me that you just need to apply the plugin  like normal.

However, please note that if you want to use Realm objects defined in the library, you'll need to expose your schema classes through a RealmModule.

Comment: This is true. Just apply the plugin and everything should work, but read this section first about schemas: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sharing-schemas